# How to get all Javascript working on html sections loaded in with JQuery .load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an `index.html` page and then 2 other `.html` files that are loaded into their respective divs within `index.html` with the JQuery .load() function.

There is content in each of these files that use different scripts from different source files. I have them all included in `index.html` but then the Javascript in the sections from the two different .html files doesn't work.

If I add all the `<script src>` to the two other `.html` files; the page runs extremely slowly and even then, the Javascript of those sections doesn't work properly.

So my question is if there's a way to get all scripts and source files to work everywhere.

And why don't these scripts work for these loaded sections if they are just being inserted into `index.html` and `index.html` has all the script src inclusions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I an trying to recreate you problem. This follows

index.html-> loads two html file in respective div with id(1,2)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
  <div id="1"></div>
  <div id="2"></div>

  <script>
    $('#1').load("load1.html"); //load html
    $('#2').load("load2.html"); //load html
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

load1.html

```
<button onclick="function11()">Load11(function 1)</button>
<button onclick="function12()">Load12(function 2)</button>

<script src="script1.js"></script>
<script src="script2.js"></script>
```

this contains two external scripts with respective function

load2.html

```
<button onclick="function21()">Load21(function 1)</button>
<button onclick="function22()">Load22(function 2)</button>

<script src="script3.js"></script>
<script src="script4.js"></script>
```

same here as above

Here in `index.html` page two external files (load1.html,load2.html) are loaded .These two files contains buttons having click function defined in their external script files. All are loaded in `index.html` and each are click are executing properly.

[Plunker link](https://plnkr.co/edit/W9NotikB7zj4YkKVGlDz?p=preview) for preview